# Fortran good practice: Is it worth to keep procedures interface in a separate file?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

I recently checked the style Intel MKL library is written and basically they use the following method to define procedures.

First fo all they have **mkl_name.fi** include file with all interfaces to the procedures e.g.

```
INTERFACE
subroutine xerbla(srname,info)
character*(*) srname
integer*4     info
END
END INTERFACE
```

and the definition is in a separate file **name.f90** which is then compiled to a shared/static library.

Second method exploits a module where similarly to the previous case only interfaces are included and procedures are defined in separate files.

Questions:

1. Is it some kind of a good practice to have separate file for all interfaces and single file for procedure definition? -- .mod/.fi + library
2. Can I put everything into a single module or a few separate one along with procedure implementation? If so, do I need to compile the module file every time I run some test program or can I just import .mod telling compiler where to find it (.mod file acts as a library)?

Comment: The visible Intel source seems to pile style inconsistencies on open source code which dates back prior to Fortran 90.  Among the potential advantages of USE vs. INCLUDE is elimination of recompilation (while continuing to use the same compiler).

Comment: I wouldn't attempt to answer this question without mentioning the potential utility of the recently-added `submodule` facility.

Comment: If you use submodules (F2008), the right way is to use a module containing interfaces. If your library is written in F77 style (or before) , then this is also a common way (.fi or .mod) to avoid argument mismatch. But between F90 and F2003, the normal way is to put all procedures in modules, making "interface modules" useless and counterproductive because one must duplicate the signature of procedures (error-prone).

Comment: @FrancoisJacq As far as I understand the reason why developers split function implementation and put them in separate files is to prevent from recompiling the whole library if some changes where made in just one of the procedures. Submodules seems to be a modern way of designing the library and this feature is supported in Intel Fortran compiler [doctor fortran](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/07/07/doctor-fortran-in-we-all-live-in-a-yellow-submodule).

Comment: @Bociek I don't think so. For instance, the true reason of sub-modules is just a clear separation between design and implementation. The fact that this also prevents cascades of recompilations is just an additional advantage, no more. Regarding the existence of .fi and .mod in old libraries, this argument is also wrong because these libraries were mostly written in F77  (=> separated compilation like in C). The objective of .fi or .mod files is only to avoid mistakes in the use of these libraries.